# Retorno de promesas en llamadas a local storag. App Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, promesas

En una app ionic estoy guardando un valor en el local storage. Mediante un servicio tengo una funcion que lo hace de manera correcta

```
async test(): Promise<String> {
  await this.storage.set("name", "Hamilton").then(() => {
  this.storage.get("name").then((val) => {
    console.log("Your name is", val);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(val);
      reject("ERROR");
    });
  });
});
```

}

Y en un componente llamo a la funcion del servicio y trato de recuperarlo ahi y hacer un console log:

```
async logForm() {
  await this.localStorageService.test().then((recoveredValue) => {
    console.log("Recupero " + recoveredValue);
  });
}
```

El problema que encuentro es el retorno del la promesa. Ya que pienso que debería de hacer ya return con lo que aparece. Si lo modifico y pongo una promesa fuera compila la app, pero el valor que obtengo es vacío.

```
async test(): Promise<String> {
await this.storage.set("name", "Hamilton").then(() => {
  this.storage.get("name").then((val) => {
    console.log("Your name is", val);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(val);
      reject("ERROR");
    });
  });
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("");
  reject("ERROR");
});
}
}
```

[image: Salida consola]

¿Alguna idea de como tratar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta haciendo:

```javascript
async test(): Promise<String> {
  return this.storage.set("name", "Hamilton") // <- Devuelve la promesa directamente
    .then(() => {
      this.storage.get("name").then((val) => {
        console.log("Your name is", val);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(val);
          reject("ERROR");
        });
  });
});
```

Y la función que lo llama:

```javascript
logForm() {
 this.localStorageService.test().then((recoveredValue) => {
    console.log("Recupero " + recoveredValue);
  });
}
```